# linux command for on file systems disk usage?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to search all file system in linux .I need a find disk space utilization of the entire filesystem based on search result ?

Comment: Try bash command: df -h

Comment: @broadband `df` is a utility program, not a bash command.

Answer (score 1):

```
df .
```

is all you need, in any directory you care to be. Or with the path

```
df /path/of/the/interesting/directory
```

In other news, has the `apropos` command stopped working?

```
$ apropos "file system"
[...]
df                   (1)  - report file system disk space usage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df       # file system usage info
df -h    # same, but in human readable format
df -a    # all system and dummy file system usage info
```

Look at `man df` for more useful info.

Answer (score 0):

"df -hl" command could help you on this.

Answer (score 0):

A portable way is:

```
df -k /ask
```

and most systems support the more readable

```
df -h /ask
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find any-path | xargs du -sh
```

for example

```
find /home/user/movies | xargs du -sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your'e best shot is using df and using a unix pipe to extract the data you need. You ould possibly use awk or grep for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things you can do, but I like the following:

Find currently growing files

```
    cd / ; touch now ; find . -newer /now -type f -print0 | du --files0-from=- | sort -n | perl -ne 'if ( /^(\d+)\s+(.*$)/){$l=log($1+.1);$m=int($l/log(1024)); printf ("%6.1f\t%s\t%25s  %s\n",($1/(2**(10*$m))),(("K","M","G","T","P")[$m]),$2);}' | tail -n10
```

Find largest files

```
    cd / ; find . -type f -print0 | du --files0-from=- | sort -n | perl -ne 'if ( /^(\d+)\s+(.*$)/){$l=log($1+.1);$m=int($l/log(1024)); printf ("%6.1f\t%s\t%25s  %s\n",($1/(2**(10*$m))),(("K","M","G","T","P")[$m]),$2);}' | tail -n10
```

Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

```
free
```

command will be very handy. Because as you want to know the disk free, you can remember it very well.
You have additional options to view the output as you want.

```
free -b     -> display usage in bytes.
free -k     -> display usage in KB.
free -m     -> display usage in MB.
free -g     -> display usage in GB.
```

Also the total RAM+Swap memory, etc.. have a look `free --help` and play with it.

Comment: `free` displays *memory*, not *diskspace* use, so is not what the OP wants.

Comment: hello.. -jens.
just go through the output of **free** command. 
it displays.. **total**, **used** and **free** memory.

Comment: no `free` doesn't display free *file system space* (it displays free *RAM*). Please read and understand the actual question. Disk space is not RAM.